# Undeclared identifier/array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm getting this error **array1 undeclared (first use this function) , array1 undeclared (first use this function)** and **[Warning] converting to int from double**

Here's the code:

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
double dist(double array1[4], double array2[4]);
{
    double Sum;
    double distance;

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter value of first coordinate";
        cin >> array1[i];
        cout<<"Enter value of second coordinate";
        cin >> array2[i];

        Sum = Sum + pow((array1[i]-array2[i]),2.0);
        distance = sqrt(Sum);
    }
        cout << "DISTANCE: " << distance;
    return distance;
}
}
```

I don't understand on where to fix this error. Could somebody help with this?

Comment: In addition to what @XiaogeSu already mentioned: You are using `Sum` uninitialized, initialize it by using `double Sum();` or `double Sum = 0.0;`.

Answer (score 1):

1. I have not seen `conio.h` for centuries. I am assuming it is Turbo C++? Use `#include <iostream>` instead.
2. You are declaring the function `dist` inside `main`. C++ does not allow this unless you use C++11 lambda grammar. Move `dist` out of `main`, remove the semicolon of the function declaration line.